# Error encontrando el mapa con Mapsforge

Tags: android, mapsforge

Estoy comenzando a desarrollar una aplicación con mapsforge, comencé por la aplicación de ejemplo básico (https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Android-App.md).

Estoy desarrollando con android studio version 1.3.1 y jdk 1.8.0, en windows 7.

Estoy usando el mismo mapa que dice el ejemplo, el cual tengo guardado en la memoria de telefono tal como indica el ejemplo.

El problema es que al correr la aplicacion desde AS en el telefono, detiene su ejecucion y se cierra. 
El log de AS dice que no puede encontrar el mapa, el error es el siguiente:

```
E/MapFile﹕ cannot read file: /storage/emulated/0/berlin.map
    org.mapsforge.map.reader.header.MapFileException: cannot read file: /storage/emulated/0/berlin.map
    at org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapFile.<init>(MapFile.java:227)
    at org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapFile.<init>(MapFile.java:205)
    at com.example.luis.mapsforge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
```

Comment: Has comprobado si en efecto en la ruta `/storage/emulated/0/berlin.map` existe dicho mapa?

Comment: si, lo he comprobado

Comment: Sé que suena raro pero... has probado a reiniciar el teléfono? haha

Comment: Tienes el permiso <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> agregado en el manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era producido por la versión android marshmallow, a la cual debía darle permisos en el dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda especificar los permisos en tu AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Pero el mensaje que indicas te puedo asegurar por experiencia que simplemente no encuentra el archivo en la ruta que te muestra mensaje de error:

```
/storage/emulated/0/berlin.map
```

Debes asegurar tener el archivo .map en la ruta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

el mapa no está dañado y esta en la ruta correcta, de hecho lo comprobe con una aplicacion de ejemplo que se pueden descargar http://ci.mapsforge.org/job/0.6.1/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/mapsforge-samples-android/build/outputs/apk/mapsforge-samples-android-oldpermissions-debug.apk, los permisos en AndroidManifest estan correctos